# Capturing audit trail information via REST

Tags: rest, http-headers, restful-architecture, audit, audit-trail

I'm struggling with coming up with the "right" way to capture audit information via a REST service.  Let's say I've got an internal REST API for an Employee resource.  I want to capture things when an Employee is added/modified/removed such as the user who did the change, the application the user was using, when it was done (assume this could be asynchronous so the user's action may have taken place at a different time than the REST call), etc.  Also, the user that initiated the change may not be the authenticated user making the REST call.

My thoughts are that those properties do not belong in the body of the request - meaning that they are not attributes of the Employee object.  They are not something that would be retrieved and returned on a GET, so they shouldn't be in the POST/PUT.  They also do not belong as a parameter because parameters should be for specifying additional things about Employees or a search/filter critiera on GET requests for Employees.

My current thoughts are to have the client specify this information in the HTTP headers.  That keeps the URL parameters & body pure for the Employee resource.  Is that an appropriate use of the headers?  Are there other options that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm working on a project with a very similar problem, and we did end up using HTTP headers to track auditing information. Actually, this was a byproduct of requiring an Authorization header which specifies the client user and application, and we use this information inside the REST service to store details in an audit log.

In your case, I don't think it's "wrong" to add custom X headers to specify the original user/application/time the request was made and storing these to an audit history in the service somewhere. Basically proxying on information via extra request headers. I also agree that these should not be part of the request body or URL parameters.